# mysql select month decrease from current time

Tags: mysql, sql

For example now is August, I want a select query with result like:

```
+-----------+
| September |
+-----------+
| October   |
+-----------+
| November  |
+-----------+
| December  |
+-----------+
| January   |
+-----------+
| February  |
+-----------+
| March     |
+-----------+
| April     |
+-----------+
| May       |
+-----------+
| June      |
+-----------+
| July      |
+-----------+
| August    |
+-----------+
```

And this order will change in next month.
Sorry if it is duplicate, I don't know what is keyword to search.

Comment: Is this data in a table?  It is unclear what you are really asking.

Comment: It seem you want to get this list from mysql, but you did not describe that any table holds that data. That mean you want to get data unrelated to your data stored in database. @sticky bit answer is an answer. The problem is - that is very bad idea to use it. usually we SELECT data from database when that data was stored before somehow. If you don't need to retrieve any data stored - do it on another side, usually application level (php, .net, java, python etc...), not mysql level. If you do have data related to this problem - provide table schemas, data samples and expected result.

Comment: It's not from nay table, I want to generate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the month of a date with `monthname()` and use `date_add()` to subtract months from a date. That is, you can build a query using `UNION ALL` and tableless `SELECT`s getting the name of the month to get the desired result.

```
SELECT monthname(date_add(curdate(), interval -11 month))
UNION ALL
SELECT monthname(date_add(curdate(), interval -10 month))
...
UNION ALL
SELECT monthname(date_add(curdate(), interval -1 month))
UNION ALL
SELECT monthname(curdate());
```

Edit:

To make this a little more dynamic, you could once create a number table.

```
CREATE TABLE integers
             (i integer);
INSERT INTO integers
            (i)
            VALUES ...
                   (-11),
                   (-10),
                   ...
                   (-1),
                   (0),
                   ...;
```

You can then select the desired range from that table, to build the list of months.

```
SELECT monthname(date_add(curdate(), interval i month))
       FROM integers
       WHERE i >= -11
             AND i <= 0
       ORDER BY i;
```

Comment: Is there a way that not use union? because I want to use it dynamicaly, not always 12 months

Comment: @DuongNhat: You could use a number table. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Create the month rows on-the-fly with `UNION ALL` or create a table and insert the records there. Couple month name and month number. Use the number for sorting. If you want to start with next month, compare with the current month:

```
select name
from
(
  select 1 as num, monthname('2000-01-01') as name
  union all
  select 2 as num, monthname('2000-02-01') as name
  union all
  select 3 as num, monthname('2000-03-01') as name
  union all
  select 4 as num, monthname('2000-04-01') as name
  union all
  select 5 as num, monthname('2000-05-01') as name
  union all
  select 6 as num, monthname('2000-06-01') as name
  union all
  select 7 as num, monthname('2000-07-01') as name
  union all
  select 8 as num, monthname('2000-08-01') as name
  union all
  select 9 as num, monthname('2000-09-01') as name
  union all
  select 10 as num, monthname('2000-10-01') as name
  union all
  select 11 as num, monthname('2000-11-01') as name
  union all
  select 12 as num, monthname('2000-12-01') as name
) months
order by num <= month(current_date), num;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NOYU32731

(This gives you the month names according to the language setting in the database. So the guy in France will see the month names in the same language as the girl in Spain when using this query.)